# Why does Java try to reserve max space from heap

Tags: java, heap-memory

When I'm trying to launch java I'm setting flags Xms and Xmx to define  min and max memory from heap

```
 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -Xms200M -Xmx1536M
```

And, in the result, Java asks to me that there is no enough free space

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

But, if I set, for example, -Xmx756 the it works fine!

So, why Java can't reserve memory? I have 16GB RAM and less then half of this memory is in use.
And why Java try to reserve max quantity of memory, because I set a range from 200 to 1536?

Comment: I don't get it, would you rather Java tell you there's not enough free space after running your code for a few hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of memory that you mention as "maximum" needs to be available (even if it is not reserved at the beginning - you can see that e.g. in jvisualvm). For some reason, most of your physical memory is not available. The most common reasons is this:

You are probably running a 32 bit version of Java. Go for a 64 bit version instead, so you can reserve more memory.

Comment: This is the way around the problem. But why in described case the problem is appears?

Comment: @Dmitrii Does my answer sufficiently answer your question?